# Possible race condition Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to understand a case I am running into with my Node/Express application.

Let's say I have the following which is a function called when a specific route is hit:

```
async function routeThatDoesStuff(req, res, next) {
     doAsyncStuff()

     res.status(200).json({ message: 'Completed' })
}
```

In this case `doAsyncStuff()` does database operations on resources that are not critical to send back to the user so theoretically we don't need to `await` it.  However, it seems that this operation does not actually complete unless I put the `await` in front.

My guess is that this has to do with the event loop etc in Node.  That potentially because the route is completing before the `doAsyncStuff()` completes, the function doesn't actually complete because Node terminated it prematurely.

My big question is how Node handles async children function execution when parent functions have already completed?

Comment: _"it seems that this operation does not actually complete"_ - what makes you think that the async operation does not complete without the `await` keyword?

Comment: @Yousaf the resource is not updated on the database

Comment: Can you share the code inside `doAsyncStuff` function?

Comment: You can't block async behavior  in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example to show that this should work:

```
const sleep = (milliseconds, cb) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(cb())
    }, milliseconds))
}

async function routeThatDoesStuff(req, res, next) {
    sleep(5000, () => console.log('done'))

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Completed' })
}
```

JSON response is shown immediately, callback is executed after 5 seconds even though the response has been sent.